# Memory stream for large data

Tags: c#, binary, memorystream

can somebody give me a hint how this works with larger data:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ser.Serialize(ms, files);
    filesBytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

files is an array of a custom type which includes information about files

ser is a binary formatter

These objects should be serialized

```
public class FileEntry
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string RelativePath { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: When I try to run this code an out of memory exception occurs

Comment: How large is the data that you are writing to the stream? Are you working with a 32 or 64 bit process?

Comment: Can you show the types that is/are serialized? And what are you going to do with those `filesBytes`

Comment: You're trying to serialize data into memory. If the data you're trying to serialize is too large, then you'll get this exception, particularly if it's done repeatedly without garbage collection taking place fast enough.

Comment: What are you doing with the `filesBytes` next? This might help determine what would be a better solution than putting it all in memory.

Comment: MemoryStream is "safe" to use for large files. However, you will be loading the entire file into memory, and it will remain there until Garbage Collection determines it a good time to recycle that memory.

more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The code should work on x86 and x64

Comment: If you want to save to `File` use `FileStream` instead of `MemoryStream`. Anyway the common advise is to split your data by chunks.

Comment: the data should be able to be as large as possible

Comment: @ErikBender then you better add a whole lot of RAM. Telling us what you're want to do beside "serialize this" will help find a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @ErikBender 8GB of RAM is plenty for a "medium" load production server.

Answer (score 2):

It allocates memory for at least twice the total size of the serialized data.

Once for the memory stream and second time for the new buffer that it need to allocate for `ToArray()`

You can use `ms.GetBuffer()` to get the internal buffer, but remember that it's most likely larger than the actual data. So you need to use it in conjunction with `ms.Length`

If the total size is very large it's better to use a file stream and return `Stream` instead of `byte[]` from your method.

Comment: Given that he's serializing an array of objects that already have file-contents in a `byte[]`, his code will at least *triple* the memory load. Definitely needs to refactor to work with the underlying streams.